# How to keep SQLPlus from trimming trailing spaces

Tags: oracle, sqlplus

If I execute the following script in SQLPlus:

```
CREATE TABLE trailing_spaces (text VARCHAR2(100))
/

-- Note that there is a blank space after 'one' and 'two'
INSERT INTO trailing_spaces (text) VALUES ('one 
two 
three')
/

COMMIT
/
```

SQLPlus automatically trims the lines and removes the trailing spaces, so that instead of inserting the value `one two three` is inserting `onetwothree`.

Does anyone know how to keep SQLPlus from trimming those lines and execute the script as it is?

Comment: What happens if you try to insert as a single line like `insert into trailling_spaces(text) values('one two three');`?

Comment: It will work, but unfortunately my scripts have line breaks and must be executed with SQLPlus

Comment: If I execute your insert statement, I get the text as three different lines. How could you get the text in one line as `onetwothree`? I am using Oracle 11.2.0.4.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it as in `SQLPLUS` :

```
SQL> CREATE   TABLE trailing_spaces (text VARCHAR2(100));

Table created.

SQL> INSERT INTO trailing_spaces (text) VALUES ('one'||'  '||
                                           'two'||'  '||
                                           'three')  ;

1 row created.

SQL> COMMIT;

Commit complete.

SQL> SELECT * FROM TRAILING_SPACES;

TEXT
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
one  two  three
```

Comment: I can't immediately find a better way, but this is really horrible... it requires significant text manipulation (you've also removed the line feeds).

Comment: @Ben. `but this is really horrible`..might be but better than not working, one is having something ,which is working. You come up with some `Elegant` solution.

Answer (score 0):

If I execute your insert statement, I get the text on three different lines. How could you get the text in one line as `onetwothree`? I am using Oracle 11.2.0.4

In my case, if I cannot alter the script, I can run the existing script and manipulate it during the selection as shown below.

```
SQL> insert into tbl1 values('one
  2   two');

1 row created.

SQL> insert into tbl1 values('three
  2   four');

1 row created.

SQL> select * from tbl1;

TEXT
--------------------
one
 two

three
 four



SQL> select REPLACE(REPLACE(text, CHR(10)), CHR(13)) as text from tbl1;

TEXT
--------------------
one two
three four
```